# Annotation where xycoords are given by data(x position) and figure/axes (y position)?

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to make an *annotation* where **xycoords** are given by *data*(x position) and *figure* or *axes* (y position)?

Comment: See [blended transformations](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Here is a demo code that confirms my answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# the x coords of this transformation are data, and the
#   y coord axes
# Note the use of different .transXXXX options
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, \
                                             ax.transAxes)
ax.plot((12,43,56),(632,0,543))

# annotate() takes `xycoords=trans`
# head location
xh = 30   #Data coordinate
yh = 0.25 #Axes coordinate
# tail location (also text)
xt = 40   #Data coordinate
yt = 0.5  #Axes coordinate
ax.annotate("v-centered", (xh, yh), xytext=(xt, yt), \
            xycoords=trans, arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '->'})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it. Although I couldn't figure it solely with your answer, but I could understand it also with the link @JohanC left above.